# How to output arbitrary stuff to stdout?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int i = 0;
        char stuffing[44];
        for(i = 0; i <= 40; i+=4)
        {
                *(int *)&stuffing[i] = 0x4004f8;
        }
        puts(stuffing);
}
```

The above terminates as soon as it gets to `0x00`, how to output all stuff in `stuffing`?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? How does it relate to stdin?

Comment: Perhaps you should read up about C-strings and null termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`fwrite`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) for outputting arbitrary binary data:

```
fwrite(stuffing, 1, sizeof(stuffing), stdout);
```

The [`puts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/puts.html) function writes a C string and C strings are terminated by `'\0'` (AKA 0x00).

**UPDATE**: In comments elsewhere you say that you want "ASCII characters to be read by `gets`". First of all, **don't ever** use `gets`, never, don't even mention its name. Secondly, if you just want ASCII characters then why go to all the trouble of stuffing the raw bytes into a `char` buffer when you could just do this:

```
printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", 0x4004f8, 0x4004f8, 0x4004f8, 0x4004f8);
```

or something similarly straight forward?

Comment: There's a link to the man page for `fwrite` up there. The 1 is the size of one element in `stuffing`.

Comment: Another way of writing it would be `fwrite(stuffing, sizeof(stuffing[0]), sizeof(stuffing), stdout);`, which illustrates the relation between the second and third parameter.

Comment: @Hippo,here `sizeof(stuffing)` won't work if it's not string,right?

Comment: @Hippo,because it should be the number of elements,which doesn't always equal to `sizeof(stuffing)`,unless the elements are `char`s...

Comment: @compile-fan: You're right. The third argument should have been `sizeof(stuffing)/sizeof(stuffing[0])`. There are numerous examples in these [Google Code Search results](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=fwrite.*sizeof.*sizeof.*%2F*%5C%5B&sbtn=Search)

Comment: The canonical way of writing an array `fwrite` is Hippo's Modified Form (wish I was still a mathematician so I could use that as a theorem name): `fwrite(array, sizeof(array[0]), sizeof(array)/ sizeof(array[0]), fp)`; when you're using a byte buffer, that boils down to a simple and idiomatic `fwrite(array, 1, sizeof(array), fp)`. Using `fwrite` for anything other than a hand packed byte buffer will give you data portability problems so you generally don't do that except for very limited cases such as temporary files and the like.